# Undefined data while using redux useSelector hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, useselector

I created a product reducer, product action, and home file along with constants file (mainly to name and store the type of the action). In `Home` I was trying to get the `products` from the backend that is already working.

I used `dispatch` and `useSelector` hooks for that function.

While I am using `useSelector` hook in the `Home` I am getting data as undefined. However when I checked by console logging in the action and the product file there the data is present.

I don't know why this error is happening.

Home.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData.js";
import ProductCard from './ProductCard.js';
import { CgMouse } from "react-icons/cg";
import "./Home.css";
import { clearErrors, getProduct } from "../../actions/productAction";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const product = {
  name: "Blue Tshirt",
  images: [{ url: "https://i.ibb.co/DRST11n/1.webp" }],
  price: "$3000",
  _id: "aditya",
};

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProduct())
  }, [dispatch]);
 
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  console.log(data);

  // const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => state.products);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Fragment>
        {loading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : ( */}
          <Fragment>
            <MetaData title="ECOMMERCE" />
            <div className="banner">
              <p>WELCOME TO ECOMMERCE</p>
              <h1>FIND AMAZING PRODUCTS BELOW</h1>
              <a href="#container">
                <button>
                  Scroll<CgMouse />
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>
            <h2 className="homeHeading">Featured Products</h2>
            <div className="container" id="container">
              {/* {products && products.map((product)=>( */}
                <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product}/>
              {/* ))} */}
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        {/* )} */}
      {/* </Fragment> */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

ProductReducer.js

```js
import {
  ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../constants/productContants";

export const productReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action ) => {
  // console.log(action.payload);
  switch(action.type){
    case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        product: [],
      };

    case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
      let obj = {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload.products,
        productsCount: action.payload.productsCount,
        resultPerPage: action.payload.resultPerPage,
        filteredProductsCount: action.payload.filteredProductsCount,
      };
      // console.log(obj);
      return obj;

    case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

productActions.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

import {
  ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../constants/productContants";

// get all the products 

export const getProduct = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({type:ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST});
        
    const {data} = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");

    dispatch({
      type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  };
}
```

Store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { productReducer } from './reducers/productReducer';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  product: productReducer,
});

let initalState = {};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  initalState
});

export default store;
```

I was trying to fetch the data from backend and was using `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hook. The data is being fetched from the backend however while using `useSelector()` I am getting that the data is undefined and I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: It's been some time since I've worked with Redux, but don't you have to connect your store to your Home component?

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen It must have been some time. The `connect` Higher Order Component hasn't been the recommended way to subscribe a component to a Redux store in quite some time. The [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook is how we subscribe/connect to the store these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const reducers = combineReducers({
>   product: productReducer,
> });
> ```

`state.product` is the state the `productReducer` provides, so if you are trying to access the `products` array of the `productReducer` then it should be `state.product.products`.

```js
const products = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);
```

or if you use object destructuring assignment

```js
const { products } = useSelector((state) => state.product);
```

Alternatively, if this is the only state you could pass `productReducer` directly to the store as the sole reducer, then `state.products` would be correct.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: productReducer,
  initalState
});
```

```js
const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const data = useSelector((state)=>state.product);
```

you can also write like this:

```
const {loading,error,products} = useSelector((state)=>state.product);
```

your reducers name is product not products (typo Here)